# Matlab R2012a strange 'find' array element error

Tags: matlab, find

I'm getting a really strange error using the find function in Matlab. Check this out!

```
A = 0:0.1:10;
```

now if I do the following I get the expected behavior:

```
find(A==5.6)
ans = 57
```

but if I do:

```
find(A==5.9)
ans =
Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

Anyone have any idea why? It is very strange.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this is just due to the precision and roundoff error associated with binary floating point represenation of the numbers.  Do `format long e` and look at A(60), and you will see that it is just not capable of expressing it exactly.  Oddly, it can express 5.9 exactly, just not 5.8 + 0.1.

Comment: This question is similar to that post but here it is more fundamental: the floating point array is created inside Matlab itself and thus it is not just a matter of a number being truncated for displaying purposes.

Comment: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/23/a-glimpse-into-floating-point-accuracy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is common knowledge for most programmers:

```
a = 0.3;
b = 3 * 0.1;
a == b
ans =
     0
```

This is because `0.1` can't be represented accurately as a binary number, thus `3*0.1` become *almost* equal to `0.3`, but with round-off errors.

You can however obviously do the following:

```
a = 0.3;
a == 0.3
ans =
     1
```

However, your problem is more complex than this... You did:

```
A = 0:0.1:10;
```

Despite what you might think, MATLAB does not create the values `[0 0.1 0.2 ...]`, but rather something along the lines of `[0 0+0.1 0+0.1+0.1 0+0.1+0.1+0.1 ...]` (but not really, **see update in the bottom**).

To illustrate this, you can have a look at the following example:

```
A = 0:0.1:0.4;
find(A == 0.3)
ans =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0

find(A == 0.1+0.1+0.1)
ans =
     4
```

This however, does not really cover all aspects:

```
A = 5.8:0.1:6
A =
    5.8000    5.9000    6.0000

find(A == 5.9)
ans =
     2
%% Found it!

A = 5.8:0.1:6.1
A =
    5.8000    5.9000    6.0000    6.1000

find(A == 5.9)
ans =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
%% Didn't find it!

find(A == 5.8+0.1)
ans =
     2
%% Found it again!
```

For the record, `linspace` results in the same results.

```
A = linspace(5.8, 6.0, 3)
A =
    5.8000    5.9000    6.0000

find(A == 5.9)
ans =
     2

A = linspace(5.8, 6.1, 4)
A =
    5.8000    5.9000    6.0000    6.1000

find(A == 5.9)
ans =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0

find(A == 5.8+0.1)
ans =
     2
```

So, what's going on? Are the following two actually the same: `x = [a:b:c]` and `y = linspace(a,c,(c-a)/b+1)`?

```
A = 5.8:0.1:6.1
A =
    5.8000    5.9000    6.0000    6.1000

B = linspace(5.8,6.1,4)
B =
    5.8000    5.9000    6.0000    6.1000

A == B
ans =
     1     1     1     1
```

It might appear that way... But the answer is no, they're not the same!

```
x = -0.1:0.1:0.3
x =
   -0.1000         0    0.1000    0.2000    0.3000

y = linspace(-0.1,0.3,5)
y =
   -0.1000         0    0.1000    0.2000    0.3000

x == y
ans =
     1     1     0     0     1
```

So, what happens when you do `A = 5.8:0.1:6`? How are the numbers created? And how can the following be explained?

```
A = 5.8:0.1:6;
B = 5.8:0.1:6.1;

A(2)-B(2)
ans =
  8.8818e-016

eps(5.9)
ans =
  8.8818e-016
```

## Update:

To counteract the accumulated errors of doing `[0 0+0.1 0+2*0.1 ... 0+k*0.1]`

"To counteract such error accumulation, the algorithm of the COLON operator dictates that:

> The first half of the output vector is calculated by adding integer
>   multiples of the step to the left-hand endpoint. The second half is
>   calculated by subtracting multiples of the step from the right-hand
>   endpoint.

[(See here)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/53912-floating-point-accurarcy-and-colon)

Also have a look [here](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ?title=FAQ&cb=7710#Why_is_0.3_-_0.2_-_0.1_.28or_similar.29_not_equal_to_zero.3F).

The lesson of course is not not compare floating point numbers using `x == y`, but rather `(x - y) < tolerance`.

Comment: I would upvote this but I don't have enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, it's a floating point issue.

If you really want to use `find` that way, try using `linspace` instead of `:` to create the array:

**Before:**

```
>> A = 0:0.1:10;
>> find(A==5.6)

ans =

    57

>> find(A==5.9)

ans =

   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

**After:**

```
>> A = linspace(0, 10, 101);
>> find(A==5.6)

ans =

    57

>> find(A==5.9)

ans =

    60
```

Comment: Please have a look at my answer Rafael, I believe it's more complex than this. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I didn't see your answer before posting mine. But you're right, it's more complex than it seems. Belive or not, I've tried "manually" doing this: `[0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 10.0] == linspace(0, 10, 101)` and all values matched! (I didn't type them all, of course, a script did it and I used copy/paste). But comparing to `(0:0.1:10)`, only 76 out of 101 values matched. That's why I suggested `linspace`, but now I guess it's not a very trustable solution.